# 2 Text field inputs into 1 record

Tags: php, html, mysql

How can i link this 2 input field basically 3 inputs into 1 record in database using php mysql

```
<form name="addtrucks" id="addtrucks" method="POST" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>">
            <label>Truck Plate Number:</label>
            <input type="text" name="truck_plate_no" id="truck_plate_no"/>
            <br/>
            <input name="button" type="submit" id="button" onclick="MM_validateForm('truck_plate_no','','R');return document.MM_returnValue"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="add" />
</form>
```

With this form the user has to type a plate number like this ABC-123
i want to create 2 input fields and 1 for ABC and another one for "-" and then finally another input field for 123 and it will insert into the database like ABC-123

Comment: If the dash is there all of the time, there is absolutely no need for three inputs.

Comment: uhmm yea just 2 inputs and dash in the middle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the dot (.) to concatenate variables like

```
$abc = $_POST('abc');
$das = $_POST('das');
$num = $_POST('123');

//this is what you would concatenate
$concat = $abc . $das . $num;
//to check just echo 
echo $concat;
```

query

```
INSERT INTO tablename(fieldname) VALUES('$concat');
```